# Allow input of HH:MM:SS into form field only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to limit the possible input into an `<input>` field to only HH:MM:SS. This is meant as a duration rather than 24h time of day (up to a maximum of 99h 59m 59s) I would prefer to do the validation of input as the user is typing rather than at the end.

This is what I've written up so far: https://jsfiddle.net/x41boh5p/

HTML

`<input type="text" id="fieldDuration" maxlength="8" placeholder="HH:MM:SS">`

JS:

```
function validateInput(entry){
  if(entry.length==1 || entry.length==2 || entry.length==4 || entry.length==5 || entry.length==7 || entry.length==8){
    if(isNaN(entry.charAt(entry.length - 1))){
        $("#fieldDuration").val(entry.slice(0, -1));
    }
  }else if(entry.length==3 || entry.length==6){
    if(entry.charAt(entry.length - 1) !== ":"){
       $("#fieldDuration").val(entry.slice(0, -1));
    }
   }
}

$("#fieldDuration").keyup(function(){
    entry = $(this).val();
    validateInput(entry);
});
```

While this works, there is an immediate problem that the input can be "overrun" if I type fast or hold down a letter.

The other issue is that in the sample above I'm not checking if the number is a valid number at that position (example: you can currently enter a number higher than 59 for min or sec). I can do that by validating every number at every position but that seems to be a wrong approach.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use an input masking plugin.

Comment: Please read [ask], where one of the bullets is "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - **but also copy the code into the question itself**." Also, "better" is an inherently opinion-based question. If you want a review of the code you have written, check the [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) of [codereview.se] to see if your question can be made on topic for that site.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you. Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned of "input masking" from Barmar's comment and used the [Inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) library to achieve what I needed.

HTML:

`<input type="text" id="fieldDuration">`

JS:

```
$("#fieldDuration").inputmask(
    "99:59:59", 
    {
    placeholder: "HH:MM:SS",
    insertMode: false,
    showMaskOnHover: false,
    definitions: {
        '5': {
            validator: "[0-5]",
            cardinality: 1
        }
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0g86azpn/2/)